# Can we edit callback function HAL_UART_TxCpltCallback for our convenience?

Tags: callback, stm32, freertos, usart

I am a newbie to both FreeRTOS and STM32. I want to know how exactly callback function HAL_UART_TxCpltCallback for HAL_UART_Transmit_IT works ?
Can we edit that that callback function for our convenience ?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You call `HAL_UART_Transmit_IT` to transmit your data in the "interrupt" (non-blocking) mode. This call returns immediately, likely well before your data gets fully trasmitted.

The sequence of events is as follows:

- `HAL_UART_Transmit_IT` stores a pointer and length of the data buffer you provide. It doesn't perform a copy, so your buffer you passed needs to remain valid until callback gets called. For example it cannot be a buffer you'll perform `delete []` / `free` on before callbacks happen or a buffer that's local in a function you're going to return from before a callback call.
- It then enables `TXE` interrupt for this UART, which happens every time the `DR` (or `TDR`, depending on STM in use) is empty and can have new data written
- At this point interrupt happens immediately. In the IRQ handler (`HAL_UART_IRQHandler`) a new byte is put in the `DR` (`TDR`) register which then gets transmitted - this happens in `UART_Transmit_IT`.
- Once this byte gets transmitted, `TXE` interrupt gets triggered again and this process repeats until reaching the end of the buffer you've provided.
- If any error happens, `HAL_UART_ErrorCallback` will get called, from IRQ handler
- If no errors happened and end of buffer has been reached, `HAL_UART_TxCpltCallback` is called (from `HAL_UART_IRQHandler` -> `UART_EndTransmit_IT`).

On to your second question whether you can edit this callback "for convenience" - I'd say you can do whatever you want, but you'll have to live with the consequences of modifying code what's essentially a library:

1. Upgrading HAL to newer versions is going to be a nightmare. You'll have to manually re-apply all your changes you've done to that code and test them again. To some extent this can be automated with some form of version control (git / svn) or even patch files, but if the code you've modified gets changed by ST, those patches will likely not apply anymore and you'll have to do it all by hand again. This may require re-discovering how the implementation changed and doing all your work from scratch.
2. Nobody is going to be able to help you as your library code no longer matches code that everyone else has. If you introduced new bugs by modifying library code, no one will be able to reproduce them. Even if you provided your modifications, I honestly doubt many here will bother to apply your changes and test them in practice.

If I was to express my personal opinion it'd be this: if you think there's bugs in the HAL code - fix them locally and report them to ST. Once they're fixed in future update, fully overwrite your HAL modifications with updated official release. If you think HAL code lacks functionality or flexibility for your needs, you have two options here:

1. Suggest your changes to ST. You have to keep in mind that HAL aims to serve "general purpose" needs.
2. Just don't use HAL for this specific peripheral. This "mixed" approach is exactly what I do personally. In some cases functionality provided by HAL for given peripheral is "good enough" to serve my needs (in my case one example is SPI where I fully rely on HAL) while in some other cases - such as UART - I use HAL only for initialization, while handling transmission myself. Even when you decide not to use HAL functions, it can still provide some value - you can for example copy their IRQ handler to your code and call your functions instead. That way you at least skip some parts in development.

Comment: Thanks Jacek.. But I didn't mean to entirely change that call back function. Can we add some extra code in that function? does that work?

Comment: And what does this callback function HAL_UART_TxCpltCallback  do?

Comment: `HAL_UART_TxCpltCallback` is a callback function for you to implement. It is defined as `weak` in HAL and therefore if you create such function anywhere in your code without `weak` in front of it, the linker will pick your implementation. That way you can implement it without touching HAL code.

Comment: Thanks @Jacek Ślimok. can I access the received buffer(data) in that callback function? Because we send only the UART handler as the parameter in the function...

Comment: This callback gets called when trasmitting completes (data gets sent out). You can access whatever you want whenever you want however, as you can define this function in any place in your code as you want. As long as it's not defined as `weak`, linker will pick it up instead of the default empty implementation.